# How to load json to a textbox with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage. It takes a json and I submit this json via button.

When I load the json with sendkeys method it doesnt work.

```py
 EMPTY_METADATAJSON=get_link("./appconfig.json")
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, UIAppPublish.metadata_page_id)))
    driver.find_element_by_id(UIAppPublish.metadata_input).send_keys(EMPTY_METADATAJSON)
```

Could u pls help me to load json?

Comment: what is the type of that element ?

Comment: a json like `code` {
    "system_service": false,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "checksum": "",
    
    "machineConfig": {
        "subscriptions": {
            "sinumerik_hf_data": {
               "payload":[
                  {
                     "sinumerikUid":"hfdd_data",
                     "period":2
                  }
               ],
               "source":"communicationAdapter",
               "quality":"high_performance",
               "isCloudMessage":false
            }
        }
    }
 }   @SaiPawan

Comment: can u plz write what u have tried ?

Comment: Edit your question and post the relevant HTML of the element that you are trying to sendkeys to along with the error message you are getting. Have you tried hard coding a simple string and then trying to send that? Does it work? Please do some more research and then edit the question with what you have tried and what the results were.

Answer (score 1):

Assign this json to one variable like below:

```
jsonToEnter = {
    "system_service": false,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "checksum": "",
    "machineConfig": {
        "subscriptions": {
            "sinumerik_hf_data": {
                "payload": [{
                    "sinumerikUid": "hfdd_data",
                    "period": 2
                }],
                "source": "communicationAdapter",
                "quality": "high_performance",
                "isCloudMessage": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pass same object as String into the text box using `WebDriver(I) sendKeys()` by strinfying your json Object like below:

```
driver.findEement(ElementLocator Of Text box).sendKeys(JSON.stringify(jsonToEnter));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try and set it via Javascript, if the element has a value-attribute.
Something like (don't know Python, sorry):

```
   webdriver.executeScript("document.getElementById('UIAppPublish.metadata_page_id').setAttribute('value', jsonToEnter)");
```